# MvvmCross Binding Image with ImageButton

Tags: mvvmcross

I try to bind Image Url to image button

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/activity_image"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    local:MvxBind="ImageUrl Type, Converter = Activity" />
```

But his does not work. If I change ImageButton to Mvx.MvxImageVIew, it will work. I also tried Mvx.MvxImageButton (If this exists), it show error.

I want to know if there is way to bind image of a imagebutton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MvvmCross can only bind existing C# Properties.

MvxImageView has an ImageUrl property - ImageButton doesn't.

To get the functionality you require:

- You could just use an MvxImageView class with a Click event?
- You need create your own ImageButtonEx class as a subclass of ImageButton - but which adds an ImageUrl property. For how to do this, see N=18 in http://mvvmcross.wordpress.com along with the source code for MvxImageView - https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid/Views/MvxImageView.cs